# Angular 5 manager property JSON

Tags: asp.net, angular, token

So now I have this Json

```
{  
  "access_token":"FJ4KJP-1mWoqNnkOLYImxeWyifVPy0YYqaMJWFpWa3uxpvOt49ap1LoVSbI35DI5XXL5mAXpn094tGGKoQR-QM1wORKhJrkAFvg0UBfM8TqT4s3UcmdSeuTS1QZ0P2ayWixuApKWr3OI5-2bCxiQgB03JBQXQu3__9ZzXZatlFDukSdARrKHFIUn74vavX0ceYlIg1MMNRTPyg2yJmLx_UaTWgpFaq5dl8gWgQzDB-l4AwTWBhBGXLkqAk46ZwmeZRZIbGdPQmxUi5_I8TuV-JCIRdRVMdXBAPAvAc9LLKhvSfGLy1Hf3dL1yUPbioZ2rrjDOVO-ey-OZUSnfE6fiA",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":1199
}
```

Where I did can not access the property "`access_token`" in Angular 5, I already used `json.access_token`, `json['access_token']` but dont work very well.

Comment: The JSON looks perfectly fine.Please be more specific on where you are trying to get the access token?
In Typescript file or in HTML property binding.

Comment: whats the error in the console when you used `json.access_token`?

Comment: is asp.net involved in your code (for this specific requirement). If not, please remove the tag

Answer (score 0):

```
var tokenResponse = { "access_token":"FJ4KJP-......",
   "token_type":"bearer",
   "expires_in":1199
}
var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
```

If you are recieving this json from somewhere outside your app boundary (as a string not a json object), you will be required to do a JSON.parse and then extract the property as above.